# CentoOS SSH Access

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6, root

I'm executed this commands with root user i'm on a CentOS 6.3 server:

```
#useradd newuser
#passwd newuser

#visudo
```

then I added this line at end of file:

```
AllowUsers newuser

#service sshd restart
#exit
```

Now, I can't access server with deployer or root user!
Both accounts return:

```
**Permission denied, please try again.**
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Why add `AllowUsers newuser` dont allows `newuser` to login by ssh?

Comment: suggestions to do what? fix the "cannot login" issue or "allow root to log in"?

Comment: check your logs for a better error

Comment: @chutz, It's possible to work around this problem and can login again by ssh?

Comment: Enable root to login via ssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config PermitRootLogin:yes and see if you can get in with root.

Answer (score 3):

`AllowUsers`, quoting `man sshd_config`, "If specified, [allows] only user names that match one of the patterns".

To work around the problem, try logging in as `newuser`, and then use `sudo -i` (if `newuser` is allowed to run the command) or `su root` (if you know the root password) to become root and take the `AllowUsers` line out. After modifying `sshd_config`, restart `sshd`.

Comment: But I can't access server with `newuser` user

Comment: Can you get on to the server at all?  Are you still logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port 22 is open:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :22
```

I'm assuming you have not turned off iptables. You can either a.) turn them off

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

Or, add a rule:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
service iptables restart
```

Then restart ssh, root login via ssh is disable by default (usually) so you would need to edit the ssh config if you want root login:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin:yes
```

Comment: "Permission denied" is normally not related to connectivity issues.